# MPI, MPI_Send/MPI_Recv send array with custom datatype

Tags: c++, arrays, mpi, custom-data-type

I am trying to send array with custom datatype, I read about MPI_Type_create_struct but I could not implement it successfully; could anyone please help me with the following:

I want to send following datatype with MPI_Send:

```
std::array<filib::interval<double>, 6>
```

and for MPI_Recv I want to receive following datatype:

```
std::list<std::array<filib::interval<double>, 6>>
```

Now the problem is ***filib::interval*** is a custom datatype I am using from some other library and I am not quite sure how to integrate this datatype with MPI.

FILIB++ Interval Library is an interval library, for docs: [Interval Library Docs](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1141885.1141893)

How should I approach this to send/receive this datatype from other processes?

Comment: You first should specify how `filib::interval` is defined. Note that if it is not a trivially-copyable type, then some form of external serialization might need to be required.

Comment: It's an external library for interval arithmetic, could you please take a look at: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1141885.1141893

Comment: It would be better to provide a link to the source code. There is some link in the article (https://www.math.uni-wuppertal.de/wrswt/software/filib/), but does not work.

Comment: The following page there are links to source code downloads: http://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/wrswt/software/filib.html

Comment: The `interval` class has a user-defined copy constructor and destructor, therefore, it is not trivially-copyable. In this case, I am afraid that you cannot use it directly with `MPI_Type_create_struct`. Note that MPI has a C API, which knows nothing about C++ classes. You may look at the Boost.MPI extension, which uses Boost.Serialization library internally for sending C++ objects with MPI. An alternative way would be to perform serialization and deserialization manually.

Answer (score 0):

FILIB++ 2.0 intervals have methods "bitImage" and "readBitImage".

See the [documentation pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjY9e-R4d_5AhXDOHoKHaMDBq4QFnoECAUQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.math.uni-wuppertal.de%2Fwrswt%2Fpreprints%2Fprep_01_4.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3DJ83zoZ92qpf87xaTXqKZ) (page 31) <sup>1</sup>

With these serialization methods it should be possible to send single  intervals or lists of intervals as byte-arrays. Note that the datatypes must be specified by both sender and receiver in the template-instantiation and there will be no type-checking on that.

<sup>1 I really tried to find a better link to this document but failed. If anyone finds something please leave a comment</sup>

Comment: Since I am implementing Boost MPI, it's giving me the error `filib::interval` does not have serialization implementation, I suppose I could use "bitImage" and "readBitImage" but I will first have to convert `std::array<filib::interval<double>, dim>` to `std::array<std::ostream, dim>`. Both methods take `std::ostream` as an input I am quite unsure how to convert `filib::interval<double>` to `std::ostream` could you please post some code, I am new to cpp.